# Is it to "refer" to a concrete type after register it

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I have an abstract type that I want to resolve with unity :
here is my concrete type implementation:

```
public class ConcreteType : AbstractType<Blog>
{
}
```

and in Bootstraper class.

```
container.RegisterType<AbstractType<Blog>, ConcreteType>();
```

That's fine.
But I need to register another type :

```
container.RegisterType<IFactory<AbstractType<Blog>>,ConcreteFactory<ConcreteType>>();
```

the problem is there is an error :

> The type ConcreteType cannot be used as type parameter 'TTo' in the
>   generic type or method
>   'UnityContainerExtensions.RegisterType(IUnityContainer,
>   params InjectionMember[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion
>   from 'ConcreteFactory' to
>   'IFactory>'.

I want Unity use the first "registration type" to resolve the second one.

How is it possible ?

EDIT :

Here is the ConcreteType Implementation :

```
public class ConcreteFactory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

and IFactory declaration :

```
public interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean the unity3d tag, rather than unity the IoC container?

Comment: Sorry... i fixed it

Comment: And is `ConcreteFactory` your type? If so, please provide *all* the relevant type declarations. It sounds like this is a generic variance issue, in the same way that a `List<Apple>` isn't a `List<Fruit>`...

Comment: I added the implementation to ConcreteFactory. Finally i would like Unity "resolve this line : container.RegisterType<AbstractType<Blog>, ConcreteType>(); to register properly this one
container.RegisterType<IFactory<AbstractType<Blog>>,ConcreteFactory<ConcreteType>>();

Comment: Okay, so I suspect you just need to change the declaration of `IFactory<T>` to `IFactory<out T>`.

Comment: You're right !!! Oh thank you !! I will search and search again otherwise !